# MongoDB: Insert without class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to insert into a mongodb database without having to specify a class to save it to, I just want to insert it, I don't want to save any of it to a class. Is there a way to just simply insert it?

Code:

```
var collection = _database<Entity>(table);
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Entity { Name = "Jack" });
```

Im trying to do it in a method like this:

```
public void InsertRecord(string table, List<string> columns, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    var collection = _database<Entity>(table);
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Entity { Name = "Jack" });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried object insead of Entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify class, you need BSON documents. Here is example how to work with them:

[mongodb c# how to work with BSON document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068772/mongodb-c-sharp-how-to-work-with-bson-document)